# Ionic get modal dialog component to close itself

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need a few modal dialogs with very similar form so decided to factor them out into a component `mycomponent` and generate an `ionicModal` which contains it. All goes well and `mycomponent` launches when required, but I can't figure out how to get a button from inside `mycomponent` to close the `mycomponent` modal dialog.

What's the right way to do this? Tutorials for `ionicModal` seem to use a globally scoped `hide` function which will be no good when I add more modals and components like this one.

```
app.component('mycomponent',{
    templateUrl: 'js/mycomponent.html',
    controller: function() {
          //various stuff
    }    
});

app.controller("mycontroller",function($scope,$ionicModal){
  $scope.mymodal = $ionicModal.fromTemplate(
      '<mycomponent options="various stuff"></mycomponent>', {
    scope: $scope
  });
});
```

mycomponent.html:

```
<ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar class=bar-positive>
        <button class="button" ng-click="hide()">Done</button>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
          <!-- various stuff -->
    </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

index.html

```
<button class="button" ng-click="mymodal.show()">Edit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an ID to your modal and create a function that changes a bool function to false. Then in your modal place `ng-show="modals[10]"`

```
<button class="button" ng-click="closeModal(10)">X</button>
```

The script:

```
var modals = [];

function closeModal(id){
    modals[id] = false;
}
```

In the controller add an ID parameter:

```
app.controller("mycontroller",function($scope,$ionicModal){
    $scope.mymodal = $ionicModal.fromTemplate(
        '<mycomponent options="various stuff" modalId="10"></mycomponent>', {
            scope: $scope
        }
    );
});
```

And read it from the mycomponent.html like you read the options parameter

```
<ion-modal-view ng-show="modals[id]">
```

Try [Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) too.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on this. Where does `ng-show` go? Did the `modals` array contain the modal objects?

Comment: I edited the answer. Try Directives too, it can be useful to what you need.

Comment: I tried this. It works for showing and hiding the modal once, but then it won't display again. I'm not sure setting `ng-show` to `false` is equivalent to calling `hide()` on the `ionicModal`?

Comment: You need to change the open function too to set the modals in the id to **true**.
The ng-show sets the css value display to none. That hides the component.